# Use Geometry Nodes to mirror the angle of incidence of a geometry towards a surface?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, mathematics

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of a light source being shot to a mirror using Geometry Nodes, so the angle of incidence and the angle o reflection are the same.

In my setup, I set the endpoint `Position` of a line to the surface of a target, and then extruded that endpoint. However, I couldn’t figure how to match the angles properly. I was only able to extrude by the `Normals` of the target’s surface, or completely wrong angles.

[image]

### This is what I’m trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: I apologize beforehand that I cannot provide a good answer, I only want to give a hint in a (possibly) right direction. In the _Vector Math_ node you have the mode _Reflect_. As far as I know this calculates the reflection vector of two vectors (the ray vector and the surface normal?). However, and that's why I cannot write an answer, I don't seem to get it to work correctly. Maybe you can find out how to use _Reflect_.

Comment: Gordon's done the job.. so not posting this as an answer, but here's [another version](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vkZxJJJo/) that modifies a 'Ray Gun' object and uses _Ray Cast_ to a given target .

Comment: Thanks, Robin Betts, for this alternative. This is version using Ray Cast is a very interesting approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recreated your nodetree to get a similar setup like you have. The reflection is calculated in the frame titled "REFLECTION ON SURFACE".

It is basically doing two things: First evaluating the normal of the target surface which you already had in your nodetree. Next using the *Vector Math* node set to *Reflect* to calculate the vector of reflection between the position on the surface and the surface normal, then using this as offset for the *Extrude Mesh* node instead of the normal in your setup.

[image: reflection reduced setup]

**Note:** Usually I would get the vector of the incoming mesh line by subtracting the position from (0, 0, 0) and then plugging it into the *Reflect* node. This would result in a vector that needs to be scaled by -1 to get the correct result.

To save some nodes, the scaling wouldn't be necessary if instead of subtracting the position from (0, 0, 0), you could switch those inputs and subtract (0, 0, 0) from the position which is simply the position itself. In this case with the lines' *Start Location* at (0, 0, 0) it works to get rid of a *Subtract* and a *Scale* node.

The "full" setup would look like this:

[image: reflection full setup]

And this is the result viewed from the side and the top. I've reduced the number of lines to 3 and the *Offset Scale* on the *Extrude Mesh* node to 0.5 so that it becomes more cleearly visible which the reflected lines are.

[image: reflection result]

Comment: Thank you. The solution was a lot simpler than I thought it would be needed. I didn't even know that you could extract that information from the position socket of the Geometry Proximity node.